# Atualizar conteúdo de DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

É possível fazer a atualização do conteúdo de uma DIV? Eu tenho uma DIV em que eu pego dados presentes nos cookies do navegador e faço um foreach para a listagem dos itens dos cookies mostrando eles para o usuário. Nessa mesma página eu tenho um botão que ao clicar chama uma função adicionando mais um item aos cookies, mas se eu abrir várias abas do navegador e adicionar outros itens aos cookies ele não faz a listagem atualizada da página atual. A minha intenção é que quando eu clicar no botão "Adicionar itens" ele atualize os itens já listados e mostre ele para o usuário. Abaixo código de listagem dos cookies para o usuário:

```
<div class="lista">
    <?php
        $myCookies = $this->getCookie('myCookies');
        foreach ($myCookies as $dados):?>
          <h3><?php echo $dados ?></h3>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Quando eu clicar no botão `<div class="add-itens" id="mydiv">Adicionar Itens</div>` eu precisaria que acontecesse um refresh na div `lista` para atualizar os itens que já estão nos cookies que foram adicionados em outras abas.

Para atualizar via Jquery eu tentei isso, mas sem sucesso.

```
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + "#mydiv");
```

Comment: Sim, usando jquery + ajax. De qualquer forma, adicione na pergunta o que você já fez para que facilite ajudar no seu caso em especifico.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mudar o conteúdo da div sem dar refresh na página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80892/13561), responde a pergunta do título, mas não responde a parte sobre *cookies* e múltiplas abas, sugiro uma edição, explicando melhor essa parte do problema

Comment: @DiegoFelipe atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido**

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "exemplo.php",
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(html){
             var headline = $(html).find('#mydiv');                                                     
             $('#mydiv').html(headline);
         }   
 });
```